# Is Python pre-installed on elementary OS?

Tags: system-installation

I have tried a few Ubuntu distributions where python comes pre-installed, therefore having some problems in package management during the development processes.

Some Linux distributions include Python on default. Does elementary OS have that, or is it coming Python-free?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it does come installed by default.

Open a terminal session (press `Supr+t` or search for *terminal* in Slingshot) and enter:

```
$ python
```

This will give you access to Python 2.

If you need to work with Python 3, the command is:

```
$ python3
```

Comment: `python3` is the correct command for python 3

Answer (score 1):

Yes,`python2` and `python3` comes in default with elementary OS.

But here `python2==python` and `python3==python3`

Open terminal and run the commands:

To find version of python2:

Open terminal and run-

```
python -V
```

or

```
python --version
```

To find version of python3:

```
python3 -V
```

or

```
python3 --version
```

For reference Open terminal and run `man python`